# freeze in UI during download content in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, user-interface

I am new to WP7 coding.
I am looking for sample code or guiding on the following task:

I had 3 html pages on remote server and I want to download the contents of each of the page and post it to 3 different panorama page (show as a textblock).

I had written 3 set of webclient to load the html page; it can be shown as where it suppose to be. My issue facing is, when/during the downloading, the UI thread is "freez" and unresponsive.

Can anyone guide me / show me the sample code that I can put the thread to background and once it finish, and shown in the UI?

This is the code that I use to download the HTML page.

```
private async void GetNewsIndex(string theN)
    {
        string newsURI = newsURL + theN;
        string fileName = theN + "-temp.html";
        string folderName = "news";

        prgBar01.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        try
        {
            Task<string> contentDataDownloaded = new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(newsURI));

            string response = await contentDataDownloaded;

            WriteTempFile(theN, response.ToString());

            string contentData = ProcessDataToXMLNews(fileName, folderName);

            WritenewsIndexXMLFile(newsIndexURI, folderName, contentData);

            DisplayNewsIndex();

        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

I'd modified the above code as per suggestion by **Sinh Pham**, and it work perfectly as it expected. But, Since I need to run 3 instant of it to download the page from different souce at he same time; the code break. Any idea?

Comment: Look into `BackgroundWorker` threads. By making long lasting calls on the UI thread you are locking it - hence the freeze.

Comment: Can you show the code that you already have so we have a starting point? That way we can just tweak your code if we can rather than come up with something completely different - and everyone lived happily ever after.

Comment: code posted at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the UI freezes when downloading and not when processing the data? From your code it seems like you're only doing

```
WriteTempFile(theN, response.ToString());

string contentData = ProcessDataToXMLNews(fileName, folderName);

WritenewsIndexXMLFile(newsIndexURI, folderName, contentData);

DisplayNewsIndex();
```

on the UI thread. Try wrap them in a BackgroundWorker instead.

Edit: something like this:

Edit2: since your DisplayNewsIndex() function cause changes in the UI, it must be executed on the UI thread.

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += delegate {
    WriteTempFile(theN, response.ToString());
    string contentData = ProcessDataToXMLNews(fileName, folderName);
    WritenewsIndexXMLFile(newsIndexURI, folderName, contentData);
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        DisplayNewsIndex();
    });
};
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: You maybe right. I do suspect the "freeze" is due to the "ProcessDataToXMLNews" function.

Comment: How do I make the 2nd line of the above code to background process? Can I just mark it in this section so it process at background? Or it need to re-write the entire function to suite the background process?

Comment: You code did work, but a minor issue. The "DisplayNewsIndex()" function have to take out from the background process as it will posted "Invalid Cross Thread process". I have to move it out after the resume. As the result of it, the display function doesnt show the content as when it being called, there wasnt any data. Is there any way that I can call the "Display" function only when the background process is finish?

Comment: Well, since your DisplayNewsIndex() function cause changes in the UI, it must be executed on the UI thread. See my updated answer again =)

Comment: I had a minor issue, as I duplicate the mention code to perform download page from additional 2 sources (total is 3), the outcome seem inconsistant; it will stop pre-matually. Any idea?

Comment: I can only guess that's due to thread synchronization. If you spawn 3 background threads, you need to synchronize their access to shared data. From your code maybe all 3 threads try to access IsolatedStorage? If so, you need to use mutex, or find a way to eliminate the need to access shared data altogether.

Comment: If I put the TaskEX.delay(30); everything back to normal. But, I think it defeat the reason that we put it to background rite?

Answer (score 2):

You can look into using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This works asynchronously on the background thread and is the same thing the `WebClient` uses internally. The WebClient simply abstracts the lower level work but, as you can see, it has the drawback of being returned on the UI thread. There's an example of how to use HttpWebRequest [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2011/04/07/httpwebrequest-fundamentals-windows-phone-services-consumption-part-2.aspx).

Comment: Should I use async together with HttpWebRequest ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? HttpWebRequest itself is asynchronous, so any calls you make with it will be performed on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

The download is complete asynchronous. But your problem is the processing of the data on the UI Thread. You should consider to do this on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

no matter where you started the .webClient() or is it async or not (I doubt you have other option than async in windows phone webClient) "IT COMPLETELY RUNS ON UI THREAD".

This is why your UI is freezed. this is actually a bug, so as other's also suggest you should consider using `HttpWebRequest` instead. What i'm going to add is a link below to my blog post which contains a Helper class called `WebDownloader` that reduces all the hassle and makes the life easier for you:

http://www.manorey.net/mohblog/?p=17#content

The only thing you need to do is this:

```
var downloader = new WebDownloader{ Url = "something" };
downloader.OnCompleted += (a, b) => { /*downloader.Result is ready!*/ };
downloader.OnFailed += (a, b) => { /*download failed!*/ };
downloader.Download();
```

you also have option to cancel your download task by calling it like this:

```
downloader.Cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is becouse you are probably downloading the content on the main thread (UI thread). When you do that it will take up all recources of that thread leaving no processor time to update the screen. Move the download to the background and it will (if this is the problem) be solved!

Comment: The `WebClient` in WP7 *always* does the downloading in a background thread. You can see in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=VS.95).aspx) that there are only async methods. However, the callbacks are raised on the UI thread, but not the download itself.